# What kind of query(UNION, JOIN, ...) I need?

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say I have this table:

```
------------------------------------------------
| id | user_id | message | reply_to_message_id |
------------------------------------------------
|  1 |       1 |       a |                null |
|  2 |       1 |       b |                null |
|  3 |       1 |       c |                null |
|  4 |       1 |       d |                   1 |
|  5 |       2 |       e |                null |
------------------------------------------------
```

My purpose of the query is to get all the messages which message col matches search query as well as all the messages which have reply_to_message_id equal to id of the result of the previous part. I hope this make sense, my brain is junk by the end of the day.

The result with search query 'a' would be:

```
-----------------
| id | is_reply |
-----------------
|  1 |    false |
|  4 |     true |
-----------------
```

I have the first part:

```
SELECT id FROM messages
WHERE user_id = 1 AND message LIKE "%a%"
```

Of course I can loop through the result of this query but it's not right and I feel like there has to be an easy way to get this result.

BTW I'm using laravel query builder but I don't think that it has what I need.

Comment: *WHERE user_id = id* why?

Comment: Messages an their answers form a tree, so you need a tree traversal or hierarchical query. That is not simple. Luckily, SO already have answers to such questions.

Comment: is the table you display the *messages* table? it doesn't look like it. What is that table?

Comment: @forpas id is just an extra condition to fetch only specific user messages

Comment: @Martin It is actually the messages table

Comment: @s0up `id` is a column in your table (probably the primary key), so this does not make any sense. Maybe you mean something more specific like `user_id = 1`

Comment: @forpas you are right. I've changed the question.

Comment: This does look similar to the question it is marked as a duplicate of. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33737203/813125 The name of what you are looking for is "a recursive query", it might look a bit scary but the basics are pretty logical.

Comment: @BjörnNilsson Yes, but I was needed a solution ASAP. It is look creepy at first, especially because MySQL version is below 5.8, so I've solved it with two queries for now. I will learn about recursive queries and variables when I'll have some time.